# Unable to change background for a Wpf toolkit autocompletebox?

Tags: wpf

How should i change the background of the wpftoolkit autocompletebox.? I tried by subscribing to enabledchanged event and changed the background of the control which is not changing at all.Can any body help.

```
<WpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox x:Name="txtBxSearch" Background="White"  IsTextCompletionEnabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="0" FilterMode="Contains"  Height="24"  Width="150" KeyDown="txtBxSearch_KeyDown"  >
        <WpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>                        
                </Style>
        </WpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox.TextBoxStyle>
    </WpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: I will gladly try to help, if you would kindly share some XAML/code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in XAML:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox
            ToolTip="Enter the path of an assembly."
            x:Name="tbAssembly" Height="27" Width="200"
            Populating="tbAssembly_Populating"                          
            >     
            <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="toolkit:AutoCompleteBox">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbAssembly, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tbAssembly, Path=IsEnabled}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Yellow" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.Style>
        </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: Yes thats right , i have done this but how do i change the background to other color when isenabled is false. I tried on isenablechanged event but dynamically it is not setting the color.

Comment: @Ershad I modified my example, check it out.